# pd.wide_to_long -> the id variables need to uniquely identify each row

Tags: python, pandas

Tenfo este df:

```
    NOM_MUN         P8A14AN_F  P8A14AN_M    P15YM_AN_F  P15YM_AN_M
0   Tuxtla Chico    106.0      114.0        2004.0     1277.0
1   Tuxtla Chico    15.0       17.0         243.0      117.0
2   Tuxtla Chico    0.0        0.0          10.0       15.0
3   Tuxtla Chico    2.0        5.0          36.0       39.0
4   Tuxtla Chico    4.0        4.0          49.0       25.0
```

E intento transformarlo con el siguiente código:

```
pd.wide_to_long(df_edu_tc_AN.reset_index(drop=True), stubnames=['P8A14AN','P15YM_AN'], i='NOM_MUN', j='Sexo', sep='_', suffix='\w+')
```

'M' y 'F' representan masculino y femenino; la idea es obtener una columna que identifique el genro y otra que identifique los prefijos ['P8A14AN','P15YM_AN'], pero este es el resultado que tengo:

```
ValueError: the id variables need to uniquely identify each row
```

Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que esta función espera un `id` único por fila, que no  tienes (`NOM_MUN` se repite), lo más sencillo es generar antes que nada, un identificador único, por ejemplo un número de fila:

```
df_edu_tc_AN.insert(loc=0, column='row_num', value=np.arange(len(df_edu_tc_AN)))
```

Y luego usarlo:

```
df = pd.wide_to_long(df_edu_tc_AN.reset_index(drop=True), stubnames=['P8A14AN','P15YM_AN'], i='row_num', j='Sexo', sep='_', suffix='\w+')

print(df)

row_num Sexo                                 
0       F     Tuxtla Chico    106.0    2004.0
1       F     Tuxtla Chico     15.0     243.0
2       F     Tuxtla Chico      0.0      10.0
3       F     Tuxtla Chico      2.0      36.0
4       F     Tuxtla Chico      4.0      49.0
0       M     Tuxtla Chico    114.0    1277.0
1       M     Tuxtla Chico     17.0     117.0
2       M     Tuxtla Chico      0.0      15.0
3       M     Tuxtla Chico      5.0      39.0
4       M     Tuxtla Chico      4.0      25.0
```

Comment: Problema solucionado, mil gracias!!